# Wicket spring security authentication without role

Tags: spring, security, wicket

In my simple wicket app I need to give users access to only one subpage- and I need to get login / pass from db table. I do not need roles. I want to use spring security. I am totally lost making this possible. Do you know any example or tutorial how to do this?

I need
- Login page (spring security)
- url filtering (acces only for logged users)
- without roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very deep topic that will require some background knowledge in order to prevent screwing it up and releasing a vulnerable app.  I recommend grabbing a good book.  Check out [Pro Spring Security in hard copy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430248181) or [the e-book (which is DRM free, thanks APress!)](http://www.apress.com/9781430248187).  That book was released 2 days ago (On Mar 20, 2013) so it is brand spanking new and up to date.  The [DRM free e-book is available for download at apress.com](http://www.apress.com/9781430248187).